# There is a problem in the encoding the string variable to float or integer in sklearn during pipeline building

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, pipeline, one-hot-encoding

I was building a pipeline in sklearn using the column transformer ,I was using the column transform for the encoding and the code runs well but during training it is showing error that "could not convert string to float: 'male' ". This error is showing after building the pipeline during training. The encoding part work well but something went wrong during the training.

I was using the titanic dataset(train.csv) which is easily available in Kaggle.

````py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline,make_pipeline
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest,chi2
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer 

a = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\SURAJ SINGH\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\train.csv")
a = a.drop(columns  = ["PassengerId","Name","Ticket","Cabin"],axis = 1)
a

xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest = train_test_split(a.drop("Survived",axis = 1),a["Survived"],test_size = .2,random_state = 3)
xtrain

tf1 = ColumnTransformer([
    ("impute_age",SimpleImputer(),[2]),
    ("impute_embarked",SimpleImputer(strategy = "most_frequent"),[6])],
    remainder = "passthrough")

tf2 = ColumnTransformer([
    ("embarke_sex",OneHotEncoder(sparse_output = False,handle_unknown = "ignore"),[1,6])],
    remainder = "passthrough")

tf3 = ColumnTransformer([
    ("scaled_age_fare",MinMaxScaler(),slice(0,10))],remainder = "passthrough")

tf4 = SelectKBest(score_func = chi2, k = 5)

tf5 = DecisionTreeClassifier()

pipeline_obj2 = make_pipeline(tf1,tf2,tf3,tf4,tf5)

from sklearn import set_config
set_config(display = "diagram")

pipeline_obj2.fit(xtrain,ytrain) ```


I already used the label encoding but still not working. Please try to answer in more compressive way because I was new to ML and data science. Any help will be appreciated.
````

Comment: Welcome to SO; please update your post to include the **full** error trace (as text) - see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the value (male/female) to 0 or 1:

```
di = {'male': 1, 'female': 0}
df.replace({'embarke_sex': di}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Examine your database. This error clearly states that you are left with some "male" values